# Fire event from a fired event sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I searched all over but I can't figure it out how must be done.

I got an event added like so:

```
this.getLetters().element.on({
        tap: me.lettersTap,
        delegate: 'span.letter-visible',
        scope:this
      });
```

and then another one:

```
this.getLetterButtons().element.on({
        tap: me.letterButtonsTap,
        delegate: 'span.letter-tap',
        scope: this
     });
```

everything works well when I tap the buttons just that in the function for the second event, I need in some
circumstances to fire the first event. I can't find anywhere how to do that.

**LATER EDIT**

[image]

If I would press the "Y", Y dissapears from the first div and appears in the second, if I press a letter from the second div, lets say K, K will disappear from the second div and will appear on the first one after "C". Now, having the position from the pic, if I press K, K dissapears from the second div, appears on the second position of the first div but here I need to fire the event on the Y, to hide the Y from the first div and show it in the second, the behavior I would have if I would click on it (but I clicked on K).

I could just play with css classes and other few checks in there, but I'm in process of learning and I'm thinking that next time I won't be that lucky to have to just change css
class, and since the action for the Y is already build why just not trigger it somehow.

Hope it's a little clear right now.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, as it is bad practise. Is there a reason why you can't just call `lettersTap()` in your second method?

Comment: I can't create the event paramenter "lettersTap: function(e) {" that e, later in the function I use e.getTarget and e.target and using console.log on it seams to be lots of objects in the event.

Comment: But you are getting the event argument in the first event listener. Can you not pass that into the second method?

Comment: Nope I can't. First is a div with buttons second is also a div with buttons, each div has his own listener and when a click is made, based on the button html, it makes an action, if I pass the event of first listener to the second function, will make a action for the second div to the first... I'll edit my post and place a screenshot to explain.

Comment: I think in your case the best solution would to only have 1 event listener for all buttons. Then when that method is called, you can detect which button is called and perform correct logic based on that.

Comment: I don't think it helps me. If I do what you say, I still have to rewrite the code to not use the event argument, because points to the pressed button. It's the same think like I would have this 2 functions and in the function that I need to fire the event I replace it with another code which does not use the event. Or my intention was to re-use the first function code not to create separate code for that event nor to rewrite both functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I was complicating too much.

Since I knew my html element which I needed to fire the event on I did:

```
this.lettersTap({
                target: {
                    innerHTML: "html of element"
                },
                getTarget: function() {
                    return Ext.get("element id"); //this returns Ext.dom.Element just like original function
                }
            });
```

Thanks,  rdougan, for support.